# How to parse JSON and store in an outside variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous, fetch

I simply want to load a JSON and store to a variable/array so that I could load the JSON api once and use the array to work with. Is there a way to fetch and store a JSON to a variable that I can access outside the fetch() or $.getJSON async functions?

I've come up with the code below, but I'm afraid it will load the JSON api everytime I call the function 'test'. Am I right?

```
 function test(callback) {
  $.getJSON('myURL', function (data) {
    callback(data);
  });
}

test(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: yes this will make a request everytime you call 'test()', it seems that your real question has to do with the scope of the variable declared in `getJSON`, just declare the variable before the `getJSON` function and you'll be able to access it both in the function and after it's fired.

Comment: When I use a global variable it returns 'undefined'. Could you provide me an example please?

Comment: when you use a global variable, it won't be populated with the data until the asynchronous getJSON completes

Comment: It never gets the value. It's just 'undefinide' in the console.

Comment: @grc - perhaps your code that uses a global is *doing something wrong™* - you haven't shown the code, so I can only assume you wrote it wrong

Comment: Don't use callbacks. Return the promise that you get. Store that promise and reuse it.

Answer (score 2):

If the data at `myURL` doesn't change, then one option is to have `test` cache the resolve value (or Promise), so that only one network request is made (and, for easy asynchronous use, use `fetch`, which returns a native Promise):

```
const test = (() => {
  let prom = null;
  return () => {
    if (!prom) {
      prom = fetch('myUrl').then(res => res.json());
    }
    return prom;
  };
})();
test()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: I didn't get the code quite well. Could you explain it further please? Are you calling '.then' from the test variable? It will access the 'test' function without calling the fetch('myUrl') again?

Comment: @grc - test is a function (the one returned by `return () => { ..... }`) not a variable

Comment: @grc `test` is a function which returns a Promise. The first time it's called, the Promise will be created; on further calls, the already existing Promise will just be returned, so your API will only be requested once.

Comment: How can I pass a variable to use inside the call test()? for example (aux variable): `test()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data[aux]['name']);`

Comment: Do I have to create another function and put test() inside it? `function teste (aux) {
test()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data[aux]['name']);
  });
}`

Comment: why the closure?

Comment: @grc Do you mean, you want to be able to fetch and cache *different* locations, and not just `myUrl`?

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky Because variables should live in the narrowest scope possible: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/388052/rationale-to-prefer-local-variables-over-instance-variables

Comment: I want to make only one parse and access different "rows" of the Json returned many different times in my web page. If I click a link, it will return part of the Json in a textbox for example. If a click link 2, it will return a different part of the Json text. But I don't want to load the URL Everytime I click the links.

Comment: @grc I think it would make the most sense to simply access the different parts of the resolved object inside the `.then` called on the function, eg: `test()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data.foo);
  });` and `test()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data.bar);
  });`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare the variable outside of the `getJSON` function:

```
var saved_data = null;

function test(callback) {
  $.getJSON('', function (data) {
      saved_data = data;
        for(var i=0; i<saved_data.length; i++){
            $('.list').append('<li data-id="'+i+'">'+saved_data[i].title+'</li>')
        }
    }, 1000);
}

test();

$(document).on('click', '.list li', function(){
    console.log(saved_data[$(this).data('id')])
});
```

The first thing about asynchronous functions is that you have to wait for them to finish (and you don't know how long that can take), before you continue with your flow. In Javascript there are two ways to address that - using the `Promise` API or using a `callback` function. In your example you have a callback that's passed to getJSON, once that callback is fired, you will have the response data inside the `saved_data` variable.

If you populate the links in the callback, then you can be sure that whenever a link is clicked your `saved_data` variable will be available, holding the data from the API response.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbow7syc/1/)

Comment: But everytime I call test(); it will load the URL again, right? I cannot use 'saved_data' outside $.getJSON, right?

Comment: you can used saved_data outside of getJSON with this code.

Comment: it doesn't return anything when I call it from outside. Could you give an example please?

Comment: you have to wait for the async call to finish, read that part again. What do you want to do with the data after you have it? Let me know the next step and I can give you a specific example

Comment: I want to parse JSON just one time (to be efficient and not load the server too many times) and store the JSON in a variable (array) that I can use with the rest of the code without calling the $.getJSON everytime. So I could print the 'data[0][1]' any where without calling the JSON api again. I don't know if I was clear. Pls let me know.

Comment: what's the next thing that you want to use it for? it's going to be available once the request is made, you need to wait for that to continue your code.

Comment: The app basically will have some links that onclick will show specific part of the Json. But I don't want to call the URL Everytime the user click the link. That's why I want to first store the JSON in an array inside the code.

Comment: So, you will populate the links inside the callback to `getJSON`, that's where you get the data you need to create the link elements. That's where I set the `saved_data` variable to the response, so from that point on `saved_data` will be available and you can just use it from then on. The point is 'from then on', you can't use it on the line where `test()` is called, the request is not done yet (can move to chat if you still need further clarification)

Answer (score 0):

You can always assign the data to a variable outside of the callback. I usually do this inside of `then()`.

```js
const apiCall = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('Data here')
  }, 1000)
})

let result

apiCall.then(data => {
  result = data
  console.log(result)
})
```

And using `async/await`:

```js
const apiCall = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('Data here')
  }, 1000)
})

const asyncFunction = async () => {
  const result = await apiCall
  console.log(result)
}

asyncFunction()
```

Comment: @JaromandaX how? Once `apiCall` is ran once, you'll have the result in `result` to reuse whenever you want in the future.